# How to display user location in reactive native maps and expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I have the user's location but I can't seem to display it on the map, here's my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
 (async () => {
    let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
      return;
    }

    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
    setLocation(location);
  })();
}, []);

let text = 'Waiting..';

if (errorMsg) {
    text = errorMsg;
  } else if (location) {
    text = JSON.stringify(location);
  }

let userLatitude = text.latitude
let userLongitude = text.longitude

return (
    <View style={styles.layout}>
      <MapView style={styles.map}>
        <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={{latitude: userLatitude,
            longitude: userLongitude}}
            title={"title"}
            description={"description"}
         />
      </MapView>
    </View>
);
```

I got most of my code off of the expo location documentation, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

if you have the user's foreground permission, you can see the location of the user directly inside the [MapView component](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md). There is a `showsUserLocation` prop that defaults to false. Set that to true and it should show up (fingers crossed ;).

```js
return (
    <View style={styles.layout}>
      <MapView style={styles.map}
         showsUserLocation={true}
         followsUserLocation={true}
      >
      // (markers, geojson etc go here)
      </MapView>
    </View>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in these variables

```js
let userLatitude = text.latitude // undefined
let userLongitude = text.longitude // undefined
```

Location.getCurrentPositionAsync() returns object:

```
Object {
  "coords": Object {
    "accuracy": 5,
    "altitude": 0,
    "altitudeAccuracy": -1,
    "heading": -1,
    "latitude": 47.0448,
    "longitude": 37.976,
    "speed": -1,
  },
  "timestamp": 1659337371953.4102,
}
```

Working code example:

```js
export default function App() {

  const [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      // permissions check
let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        // do something when permission is denied
        return;
      }

      const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();
      setUserLocation(location);
    })()
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
        {userLocation && <Marker coordinate={userLocation.coords} />}
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
}
```